# Como manter a linha de uma table bootstrap com aparência de ativa

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

gostaria de saber como manter uma linha como ativa da tabela por default, sem passar o mouse, no caso ela seria para ser selecionada uma de 4 opções disponíveis em cada linha.

Ex:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No caso deixar essa primeira linah já destacada e conforme eu utilizar as setas ou um button ela ir descendo, para as outras opções.

Comment: Que 4 opções disponíveis? Que botão, onde? Cade o código da tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as **Contextual Classes** do bootstrap:

v 4.3 - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#contextual-classes

v 3.3 - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-contextual-classes

No seu caso, para manter ativo mesmo sem passar o mouse (hover), voce pode utilizar:

Classe `table-active` nas `<tr>` caso esteja na versão **4.3**.

```
<tr class="table-active">...</tr>
```

Class `active` nas `<tr>` caso esteja na versão **3.3**.

```
<tr class="active">...</tr>
```

Inclusive, as classes podem ser utilizadas nas células.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado amigo.